# there is data in db but "get" call return null for userName

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-data-jpa, postman

i added spring security layer to my project. i wrote create user method. i added db but i called get method in postman return null value. only userName get null. id and password get true. so findAll() method return null only for userName

[db value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UVQMO.png)

[return postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oddjT.png)

User

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class User implements UserDetails{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    @Column(name = "userName")
    private String userName;
    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;
```

UserRepository

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Integer> {

    User findByUserName(String userName);
```

UserManager

```
@Service
@AllArgsConstructor
public class UserManager {
    private UserRepository userRepository;
    private PasswordEncoderConfig passwordEncoderConfig;
    private ModelMapperService modelMapperService;


    public Result createUser(CreateUserRequest createUserRequest){
        User checkUser = userRepository.findByUserName(createUserRequest.getUserName());
        if(checkUser != null){
            return new ErrorResult("User available");
        }
        createUserRequest.setPassword(passwordEncoderConfig.bCryptPasswordEncoder().encode(createUserRequest.getPassword()));
        User user = this.modelMapperService.forRequest().map(createUserRequest, User.class);
        userRepository.save(user);
        return new SuccessResult("Add User");
    }

    public DataResult<List<GetAllUsersResponse>> getAllUser(){
        List<User> users = userRepository.findAll();
        System.out.println(users);
        List<GetAllUsersResponse> responses = users.stream()
                .map(user->this.modelMapperService.forResponse()
                        .map(user, GetAllUsersResponse.class)).collect(Collectors.toList());
        return new SuccessDataResult<List<GetAllUsersResponse>>(responses, "Data");
    }
}
```

UserController

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/user")
@AllArgsConstructor
public class UserController {
    private UserManager userManager;

    @PostMapping("/add")
    public Result createUser(@RequestBody CreateUserRequest createUserRequest) {
        return userManager.createUser(createUserRequest);
    }
    @GetMapping("/getall")
    public DataResult<List<GetAllUsersResponse>> getAllUser() {
        return userManager.getAllUser();
    }
}
```

GetAllUsersResponse

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class GetAllUsersResponse {

    private int id;
    private String userName;
    private String password;
}
```

Mapper

```
@AllArgsConstructor
public class ModelMapperManager implements ModelMapperService{
    private ModelMapper modelMapper;
    @Override
    public ModelMapper forResponse() {
        this.modelMapper.getConfiguration()
                .setAmbiguityIgnored(true)
                .setMatchingStrategy(MatchingStrategies.LOOSE);
        return this.modelMapper;
    }

    @Override
    public ModelMapper forRequest() {
        this.modelMapper.getConfiguration()
                .setAmbiguityIgnored(true)
                .setMatchingStrategy(MatchingStrategies.STANDARD);
        return this.modelMapper;
    }
}
```

i created a new user. when i want to show all users with get call i saw null value in userName.

Comment: Can you show your mapper class ?

Comment: Can you change matchingStrategy for the response to MatchingStrategies.STANDARD ? It should fix the problem

Comment: unfortunately didn't fix the problem. findAll() method get null value only userName. id and password return true and userName null value. @AndreiLisa

Comment: Change @Column(name = "userName") to @Column(name = "user_name"). in entity class

Comment: didn't fix but i changed userName to name in entity fix the problem. interesting. can't i use with userName ?